# keeps on inserting data every refresh PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have this code here. It successfully inserts data into database but every time I refresh my browser I receive this message from the browser **"The page that your looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any actions you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?"** When I press continue, it Inserts the same data that I inserted. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? I just started learning PDO.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db = "pdotest2";
$pass = "";

$dbase = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);

if(isset($_POST['firstname']))
{
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbldata(firstname, lastname) VALUES(:firstname, :lastname);";
$query = $dbase->prepare($sql);
$results = $query->execute(array(
    ':firstname' => $fname,
    ':lastname' => $lname
));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
<br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
    $query1 = $dbase->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata");
    echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=5>";
    while($row = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Every help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: thanks brother.. I get the idea now but I have no idea about the 3xx success and GET.

Answer (score 2):

This message appears because you filled out the form, then clicked "submit". On that page you are viewing after submitting, you hit the refresh button. It is standard for browsers to "resubmit" what you have submitted previously when you hit refresh.

If you want it to not "resubmit", type in the URL and press enter. That way there is no submission data. Only if you click submit after that it should send more data and insert another row.

An easy method is to just click into the address bar (the address should already be present) and press enter. This will reload the page without resubmitting the data.